# Free Amtrak Lounge Access with No Ticket

Tags: loyalty-programs, amtrak, lounges

[Amtrak Select Plus](https://amtrakguestrewards.com/info/plus) and [Select Executive](https://amtrakguestrewards.com/info/executive) statuses provide

> Unlimited access to ClubAcela®, Amtrak's Metropolitan Lounge<sup>SM</sup>, First
>   class lounges and United Club lounges.

**Can an Amtrak Select Plus/Executive member enter an Amtrak lounge at any time, even if he or she does not have a train ticket?**

Unlike airport lounges, Amtrak lounges are *outside* the security perimeter; therefore, any ticket checks would need to happen at the lounge entry desk.  The rules say "unlimited access," which suggests to me that they can be accessed at any time.

[United Club Members also have free access to Amtrak lounges](http://United%20Club%20Members), but might be subject to different rules.  I am specifically interested in travelers with Amtrak status, but others might be interested in whether answers apply to United Club members, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be possible to enter without a train ticket for these members.

On their [lounge page](http://www.amtrak.com/station-lounges), Amtrak lists who can access them. They list those specifically needing a ticket:

> - Amtrak passengers with a same-day ticket (departing) or ticket receipt (arriving) in First Class or sleeping car accommodations.
> - Complimentary ClubAcela Single-Day Pass holders. Same-day travel ticket not needed.

However, regarding the Amtrak members, the ticket is not needed:

> - Amtrak Guest Rewards members with a valid Select Plus or Select Executive member card.

So it looks like the agent at the counter would not ask to see a ticket to let a member of Amtrak Select Plus or Select Executive enter there. You need to have the card, though - I don't know if Amtrak  systematically sends a card to all its members.